# Access to api with certificate on localhost (vue.js app)

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, ssl, vue-cli

I have vue.js app build with vue-cli. App is located at dev.example.com and the rest api is at dev.example.com/api/v1/. Backend add ssl certificate to protect dev. And now on localhost I get error 400 when I try to make a request to api. To access the dev domain i have p12 certificate. How can I configure *vue.config.js* or *axios* to continue local development?

```
<head>
  <title>400 No required SSL certificate was sent</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="white">
  <center>
    <h1>400 Bad Request</h1>
  </center>
  <center>No required SSL certificate was sent</center>
  <hr>
  <center>nginx</center>
```

vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        proxy: {
            "/api/v1": {
                target: "https://dev.exmpaple/api/v1",
                changeOrigin: true,
                pathRewrite: { "/api/v1": "" },
            },
        },
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you should generate your own cert and provide keys in config.

```js
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    https: {
      cacert: './server.pem',
      pfx: './server.pfx',
      key: './server.key',
      cert: './server.crt',
      passphrase: 'webpack-dev-server',
      requestCert: true,
    },
  },
};
```

Also, you can try to set `https` for automatic ssl generating.

```js
devServer: {
    https: true,
  }
```

### Webpack Version above v4.4.0+

In new webpack version `https` option was deprecated, you need to specify `devServer.server.options` to use own certificates:

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    server: {
      type: 'https',
      options: {
        ca: './path/to/server.pem',
        pfx: './path/to/server.pfx',
        key: './path/to/server.key',
        cert: './path/to/server.crt',
        passphrase: 'webpack-dev-server',
        requestCert: true,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: https option is now deprecated